# CopyFromScreen works on 32-bit Win10 computer but not 64-bit

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, 32bit-64bit

I developed this code on a Win10 32-bit machine. I put some graphics into a panel, pnlFull. Then I copy the contents of pnlFull and save them as a bmp file on the disk. Debug/Release/AnyComputer/32-bit/64-bit all work fine on the 32-bit machine. Release 32-bit/64-bit/AnyComputer don't work right on the 64-bit machine. On the 64-bit machine, the origin of the copy is somewhere outside pnlFull. Depending on where my form is on the screen, the origin of the copy even lies outside the form. I'd really appreciate any help.

```
Private Sub Capture_Preset()
    Using tmpImg as New Bitmap(pnlFull.Width, pnlFull.Height)
    Using g as Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImg)
    g.CopyFromScreen(pnlFull.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)), New Point(0, 0), New Size(pnlFull.Width, pnlFull.Height))
    End using
    tmpImg.Save("C:\ProgramData\Paedia\DiablocData\PresetImg(" & PresetNumber & ").bmp", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    End using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [**`Control.DrawToBitmap()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need. It will make the control draw itself onto a bitmap of your choice:

```
Using tmpImg as New Bitmap(pnlFull.Width, pnlFull.Height)
    pnlFull.DrawToBitmap(tmpImg, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), tmpImg.Size))
    tmpImg.Save("C:\ProgramData\Paedia\DiablocData\PresetImg(" & PresetNumber & ").bmp", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
End Using
```

Comment: @Nordic_1 : Glad to hear! Please mark this as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on the left of my post.

Comment: Done. Much appreciated.